# How to call webservice from shell script ? Any webservice restfull or normal

Tags: shell, unix

How do I call a webservice from a shell script? It could be any webservice, restful or normal.

Can I use `curl`, or some other command? Any examples or links would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Use -d option to curl if you wish to post query string parameters.

http://blogs.plexibus.com/2009/01/15/rest-esting-with-curl/

Answer (score 1):

Create the file by running the command 
    nano scriptName.sh
copy and paste the code below into the terminal

```
#!/bin/sh

# This is a comment!

curl 'http://example.com'
```

Now give the right permission to the file by running

> chmod 755 scriptName.sh

executable

> ./scriptName.sh

to test if it works

Add the script to the cron tab using the following example
In the terminal run

crontab -e

Add the cron to the crontab to execute the script.

this example shows how the script can be executed everyday at 4am

> 0 4 * * * /home/joe/scriptName.sh